# basic firebase URL structure?

Tags: firebase

I am building a very simple cron job backup system for a friend's firebase app; 
I have PHP code, using firebase-php that can communicate with the firebase and the API docs state that adding the'?format=export" parameter will retrieve a .json file.  Cool, so far.

My question is this: What path (after the firebase URL) is required? 
The API doc appears to state that it should be /.json but it returns a 404 /json/ works on the simulator, but also returns a 404 in testing

(note: looking for a single text file, similar to the "Export json" data dashboard, if possible)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The path defined the portion of the Firebase data tree that is being loaded. That means that you can load `/any/possible/string` and it will return a value, though that value is likely to be `null` unless you've written data to that path. Also note that without a defined extension (i.e. `.json`) you'll be attempting to load Firebase's in-browser graphical debugger.

In short, if you're using the REST API, you'll always want to end your paths in `.json`, but nothing else is *required*, i.e. `https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/.json` is perfectly valid, and would download your entire Firebase. The `format=export` parameter ensures that any Firebase priority values are preserved in your JSON output, under the key `.priority` at any node, where they would normally be excluded.

Comment: Thanks - this gets me a LOT closer  adding ".json?format=export" gets me a confusing "{
  "error" : "Export format must be export if present"
}"  message as a return value

Comment: @user3649779 Check to see if something is being escaped improperly on your request, and that the querystring is being sent properly, testing your URL in the browser for correctness. For example, [https://test-url.firebaseio-demo.com/.json?format=export](https://test-url.firebaseio-demo.com/.json?format=export) works as expected.

Comment: thanks again - working now after adding "&print=pretty" to the querystring. no clue why, but it works. LOL